# Retrieve zip file from a predefined ftp link using bat or cmd file

Tags: ftp, cmd, unzip

I have a pre-defined ftp link with a zip file on the other end that I want to save to a directory on my cloud server (running Windows Server 2008). Once the zip file has been saved to a specified directory, lets say "c:\MyZipFiles\ZipFile-1.zip" for example, I want to unzip the file so that all files contained within the zip file are accessible within the same directory. I'm currently doing this manually and I want to automate this process by creating a .bat or .cmd file that will perform these steps for me.

Once the zip file is unzipped, I have a task in the Task Scheduler of Windows Server Manager ready to use the unzipped files for other things.

The pre-defined link looks something like this:
ftp://idx.realtor.com/idx_download/files.zip

I would greatly appreciate anyone who can help me with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch file

```
ftp -s:ftp_cmds.txt host-name-goes-here
unzip local-file.zip
exit
```

ftp_cmds.txt

```
username-goes-here
password-goes-here
cd remote-directory-goes-here
get files.zip local-file-name-goes-here.zip
quit
```

This the batch file uses "unzip" to unzip the archive you can find it here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unzip.htm
Either put the binaries in the same directory or put them somewhere else and set your windows PATH

I used my own ftp to test most of this. Your ftp was offline for me, so it might take some tweaking but this should put you in the right direction.